# draw as well as addSubview in a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, drawrect

Hi
I want add two buttons on a UIView using Interface Builder, and draw a line between these two buttons. How is this possible? Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple option without using drawrect is to just put a thin UIView between the two buttons.  Set the view's background color to the line color you want.

**Edit:**
You could still use thin UIViews and toggle their visibility as needed.
If you still want to draw the lines, you might want to create a custom UIView.

```
@interface CustomView : UIView {
    UIButton *button1;
    UIButton *button2;
}
@end

@implementation CustomView

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 80, 30);
        [btn1 setTitle:@"Button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button1 = btn1;
        [self addSubview:btn1];

        UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 60, 80, 30);
        [btn2 setTitle:@"Button2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button2 = btn2;
        [self addSubview:btn2];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (button1.selected)
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 45.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150.0, 45.0);
    if (button1.selected)
    {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 180.0, 35.0);      
    }
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    button1.selected = !button1.selected;
    button2.selected = !button2.selected;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Comment: That is a good option, but I want to draw the line in parts. Basically, one part of line is drawn when one button is in selected state and other in normal state else it is not drawn, and other part remains as it is. Same for vice-versa

Comment: Updated the example with something closer to your description.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I think this will do. If i get any difficulty I will comment it, else i will mark it as the answer. Once again thanks.